# Send Large Data using Bluetooth Low Energy between windows and ios , also between windows ans android

Tags: android, ios, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project which need to connect the windows PC and iOS device with bluetooth and also need to connect the windows PC and android device using Bluetooth Low Energy and we are able to connect and send data within cross platform, but now we need to send large data(~500 bytes) using the ble apis, for that we have some doubts:

- **-> Maximum data to be sent and receive in windows, android, iphone**
- **->Maximum number of packets which can be sent and receive by all platforms**
- **-Will it affect the speed of transformation for any platform**

I am searching for all these three platforms but could not get any success, can you please guide me for this.Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can send 20 bytes at a time. There is no maximum number of packets you can send. It won't be particularly fast compared to wifi

Comment: thanks for your reply , but I have read that: This is the number of packets that can be sent in each connection interval. According to the Bluetooth specification, the maximum packets per connection interval is 6, but iOS limits this to 4. See https://atmosphere.anaren.com/wiki/Data_rates_using_BLE#Packets_Per_Connection_Interval

Comment: What I meant is that there is no limit to the number of packets you can send per connection. The lower level wireless link layer stuff is abstracted from the app, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: ok.. do you have any link for sending large data in cross platform using packets ?

Comment: You basically just write to a characteristic 20 bytes at a time until all of the data has been sent. This Apple example shows the approach https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: hmm I will definitely try this one, but still not sure about windows and android and about the speed if more that 10 data packets are sent...

Comment: What operating system shouldn't really matter in terms of speed. It's the underlying BLE protocol that limits the speed. Important things are the connection interval and that you use notifications/writes without response instead of indications/writes with response.

Comment: If at all possible don't use BLE but just standard old fashioned Bluetooth which is far better for this.

Comment: as per requirement we have to work on BLE for this, I have also made a demo with the help of RFCOM , but now we need to implement this with BLE apis.